# Calculate first week of the month from a particular day in Date picker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, calendar, momentjs, daterangepicker

For example if 1st June is coming on Thursday than Week-1 of June should be from 5th as it's a Monday.

I want to disable alternate weeks in the calendar but the week should start from Monday for the first month only.

I can use momentJS also

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

1. Get the start of month with `.startOf('month')`, I used `.add(1, 'month')` for pass to next month
2. Check if the date is a Monday using `.day()` that return you a number from 0 to 6 (Sunday - Saturday), so Monday is the number 1
3. If it isn't a Monday add to date a week with `.add(1, 'week')` and set the day at a Monday using `.day()` but this time pass at the method the number of week that you want set (1)

```js
const MONDAY = 1;

let nextMonthStartDate = moment().add(1, 'month').startOf('month');

if (nextMonthStartDate.day() !== MONDAY) nextMonthStartDate = moment(nextMonthStartDate).add(1, 'week').day(MONDAY);

console.log(`The first complete date of ${nextMonthStartDate.format('MMMM')} start at the ${nextMonthStartDate.format('LLLL')}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This code write all first complete week of current year.

```js
const numberOfMonth = 11;

const yearStartDate = moment().startOf('year');

const MONDAY = 1;

for (let i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
  let monthStartDate = moment(yearStartDate).add(i, 'month').startOf('month');
  if (monthStartDate.day() !== MONDAY) monthStartDate = moment(monthStartDate).add(1, 'week').startOf('week').day(MONDAY);
  console.log(`The first complete date of ${monthStartDate.format('MMMM')} start at the ${monthStartDate.format('LLLL')}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks, How can I disable alternate weeks using this? I tried muing multiple loops but I am unable to get desired output. I want to disable alternate weeks i.e Monday-Friday. All the weekends would be disabled by default. I am using daterangepicker (https://www.daterangepicker.com/). Appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, do you want a week yes an one not? I never used this library, from documentation I saw there is a option called `isInvalidDate` that it's a function that must return a boolean value. But I'm not sure that it is what you need, can you add a working example in your question or in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Solved my issue, Thanks for the help! :)